# Extract words from cell function

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this function to extract a word from a cell.

```
Function FindWord(Source As String, Position As Integer)
    Dim arr() As String

    arr = VBA.Split(Source, " ")
    xCount = UBound(arr)

    If xCount < 1 Or (Position - 1) > xCount Or Position < 0 Then
        FindWord = ""
    Else
        FindWord = arr(Position - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

I am looking for a way to extract multiple words instead of just one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `ParamArray` parameter to specify any number of Position parameters.

Something like this:

```
Function FindWord(Source As String, ParamArray Position())
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim xCount  As Long
    Dim ReturnString As String

    arr = VBA.Split(Source, " ")
    xCount = UBound(arr)

    For i = 0 To UBound(Position)
        If (Position(i) - 1) <= xCount And Position(i) > 0 Then
            ReturnString = ReturnString & " " & arr(Position(i) - 1)
        End If
    Next

    FindWord = Trim$(ReturnString)
End Function
```

then call it like

```
=FindWord(A1,3,2,1)
```

specifying as many Positions as desired

Comment: For better readability you can also do a for each loop through Position instead of a for loop/xCount.

Comment: @Issun [see this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129931).  It says don't use `For Each` on an array as you will ge _"a substantial decrease in performance"_

Comment: Good to know, Chris! I imagine this will only be noticeable on large arrays, but always good to know that the ol' for loop is king.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use a `Regexp` to also validate that the strings were actually words.

This function returns a 1D variant array that either returns

- all valid strings if the optional positon sequence is not specified
- the valid strings in the user specified order

Calling the function with
  `Y = GetWord("I am a test 109 sample", 4, 1)`
Puts *test* in `X(1)`, *I* in `X(2)`

[image]

*test*

```
Sub TestCode()
Dim Y
Y = GetWord("I am a test 109 sample")
Y = GetWord("I am a test 109 sample", 4, 1)
End Sub
```

*main*

```
Function GetWord(strIn As String, ParamArray Order()) As Variant
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegexMC As Object
Dim objRegexM As Object
Dim X
Dim lngCnt As Long

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With objRegex
   .Pattern = "\b[a-z]+\b"
   .ignorecase = True
   .Global = True
If .test(strIn) Then
    Set objRegexMC = .Execute(strIn)
    If UBound(Order) < 0 Then
    'get all matches
    ReDim X(1 To objRegexMC.Count)
    For Each objRegexM In objRegexMC
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
        X(lngCnt) = objRegexM
    Next
    Else
    ReDim X(1 To UBound(Order()) + 1)
    For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
        If Order(lngCnt - 1) <= objRegexMC.Count Then X(lngCnt) = objRegexMC(Order(lngCnt - 1) - 1)
Next        Next
    End If
GetWord = X
End If
End With
End Function
```